# TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=192.168.1.249:35230

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to deploy hyperledger fabric(v1.4.3) solo mode on multi-machines, the role-ip map is as following:

```
orderer          192.168.1.251
peer0.org1       192.168.1.249
peer0.org2       192.168.1.248
peer1.org1       192.168.1.247
peer1.org2       192.168.1.246
```

I copy the `fabric-samples/first-network` into `first`, and delete some files, the `first` folder contains:

```
├── base
│   ├── docker-compose-base.yaml
│   └── peer-base.yaml
├── channel-artifacts
├── configtx.yaml
├── crypto-config.yaml
├── docker-compose-cli.yaml
    byfn.sh
```

I keep the `crypto-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml` the same as the `fabric-samples` gives and just change the `docker-compose-cli.yaml`.

The `orderer`'s `docker-compose-cli.yaml`:

```yaml
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

the `peer0.org1`'s `docker-compose-cli.yaml`:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  peer0.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:192.168.1.251"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:192.168.1.247"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:192.168.1.248"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:192.168.1.246"

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - SYS_CHANNEL=$SYS_CHANNEL
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051             # change in different peer
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP                              # change in different peer
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt      # change in different peer and org
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key       # change in different peer and org
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt      # change in different peer and org
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp      # change in different org
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:192.168.1.251"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:192.168.1.249"
      - "peer1.org1.example.com:192.168.1.247"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:192.168.1.248"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:192.168.1.246"
```

the other peer changes as the comment in above yaml file.  I use the `./byfn.sh generate` to generate the channel-artifacts on each peer and orderer, and then in peer0.org1（192.168.1.249）cli container, I install the chaincode successfully but when i instantiated the chaincode i see the orderer console throw the error:

```
[core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 009 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=192.168.1.249:58812
```

and I notice the error also happens between the peers. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: I tried to add SANS to the crypto-config.yaml but failed, plz let me kown if you require additional information!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing `-channelID mychannel` parameters when I create the `genesis.block`.